# How to create :keywords?

Tags: elisp, symbols

**Q:** How does one create and use `:keywords`?

Consider a (naive, apparently) attempt to access the following toy alist:

```
(setf alist '((:key-1 "Key no. 1")
              (:key-2 "Key no. 2")))

(assq :key-1 alist)                 ; => (:key-1 "Key no. 1")
(assq (make-symbol ":key-1") alist) ; => nil
```

The first key works as expected, but the second key does not.  Insofar as there is no obvious `make-keyword` function, how does one create and use a keyword?

Original motivation: I need to transform a string into a lookup key that is a symbol onto which I can `put` properties.

*In the process of formulating this question, I've gotten to at least part of the answer, which I'm posting separately.  I'm hoping brighter minds than mine can improve upon it.*

Comment: `(eq :foo (read ":foo"))`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are right that `make-symbol` will create a keyword that is not `eq` to any existing keyword, and `intern` might pollute the global obarray with the new symbol. In between those, you have `intern-soft`, which returns the symbol if it has already been created, or `nil` if it hasn't:

```
ELISP> (intern-soft ":key-1")
nil
ELISP> :key-1
:key-1
ELISP> (intern-soft ":key-1")
:key-1
```

This should be suitable for your purpose: if the keyword doesn't exist, it cannot be present in the alist, so there is no need to create it just to check whether it's there.  Something like:

```
(let ((maybe-keyword (intern-soft ":key-1")))
  (and maybe-keyword (assq maybe-keyword alist)))
```

Comment: Clever -- I'd seen `intern-soft` but hadn't thought to use it this way.

Comment: This is a great solution but be careful to call `intern-soft` *after* any other code has run, which should have interned those keywords. I ran into a problem using macros, interning the symbols before the actual parsing code ran, which then re-interned the symbols, causing a mismatch. Regardless, thanks to @legoscia for this nice solution!

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps I'm not understanding the question correctly.  But if you *want a keyword* (i.e., you want to satisfy `keywordp`) then you *want the symbol to be interned in the global obarray*, `obarray`.

It **must** be interned there to satisfy `keywordp`, AFAICT, and `C-h f keywordp` says so.

So the answer to your question, AFAICT, is just to **use `intern`**.

I feel like you are perhaps not asking your real question - seems like an XY question. What are you really trying to do? (Maybe pose that as a separate question.)

[In answer to your comment that interning "*is not `:keyword` specific, as it applies to all symbols*": Correct, interning is not specific to keywords. But interning (in `obarray`) and using a `symbol-name` that starts with `:` is specific to keywords.]

Comment: It's most certainly an XY question in the sense that I'm trying to Y, but got really interested in X in my attempt to get to Y.  Let me give some thought to how to pose the question about Y in such a way that it's useful to others as well.

Comment: Great. That will be helpful. Thx.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a partial answer to this question.  The short and not entirely satisfying version seems to be: use `intern`.

`:key-1` satisfies both:

```
(symbolp :key-1)                    ; => t
(keywordp :key-1)                   ; => t
```

While `(make-symbol ":key-1")` satisfies the first but not the second:

```
(symbolp (make-symbol ":key-1"))    ; => t
(keywordp (make-symbol ":key-1"))   ; => nil
```

Now, the docstring for `make-symbol` says that it will:

> Return a newly allocated uninterned symbol whose name is NAME.

Mmmkay, and the docstring for `keywordp` says that it will:

> Return `t` if OBJECT is a keyword.
>   This means that it is a symbol with a print name beginning with `:`
>   interned in the initial obarray.

So it appears that `intern` will work:

```
(assq (intern ":key-1") alist)      ; => (:key-1 "Key no. 1")
```

Because `intern` will:

> Return the canonical symbol whose name is STRING.
>   If there is none, one is created by this function and returned.
>   A second optional argument specifies the obarray to use;
>   it defaults to the value of `obarray`.

But this doesn't seem to be `:keyword` specific, as it applies to all symbols.  By default, it also appears to pollute the global `obarray`, which may or may not be A Big Deal.